# jquery, get id/class/other from clicked item and reuse

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a.color2030').click( function() {
        jQuery('tbody').hide();
        jQuery('tbody.color2030').show();
    });
    jQuery('a.color2031').click( function() {
        jQuery('tbody').hide();
        jQuery('tbody.color2031').show();
    });
...
...
    jQuery('a.color2037').click( function() {
        jQuery('tbody').hide();
        jQuery('tbody.color2032').show();
    });
});
```

But would like not to have to repeat the block of code for each link.
I can get the id from the link in any way. It could be color2030 etc.

I have tried:

```
<a href="#color2030" class="color2030" id="test2030">
<a href="#color2031" class="color2031" id="test2031">
<a href="#color2032" class="color2032" id="test2032">
```

And in jQuery:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    // this works
    var id = 'test';
    alert(id); // will alert 'test'

    // this does not work
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  //update2: should have been jQuery(this...
    alert(id); // no alert but error on page
});
```

But I cannot seem to get hold on the id. The "var id" line seems to have an error or so.
Is there another way to get read an id/class or other tag from an a-tag when pressed?

BR. Anders

UPDATED:
due to a typo that two persons spotted in not much more than 30 sek!

UPDATE2 and solved!
The error I could not spot was the $(this) where it should have been jQuery(this) in the 'var id' line

Final update with solution
This is was is doing the trick

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a').click( function() {
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);

        jQuery('tbody').hide();
        jQuery('tbody.'+id).show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few bugs.  Here is the code refactored and working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('a').click(function() {
                alert(this.id);
            });
        });
    </script>   

</head>
<body>

<a href="#color2030" class="color2030" id="test2030">test2030</a>
<a href="#color2031" class="color2031" id="test2031">test2031</a>
<a href="#color2032" class="color2032" id="test2032">test2032</a>

</body>
</html>
```

1. onclick isn't a jQuery method.  Please use click.
2. this is an HTML DOM Anchor Object.  Therefore, calling the property id will return its value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The onclick was a typo, but the jquery vs. # I would never have found out. Thanks a lot. now I can go to bed

Answer (score 4):

`onclick` should be `click`:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are right with the typo. There is also another error since I use jQuery instead of # but mixed it here

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your event:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

You're better off using Firebug or Web Developer to do this kind of debugging. That being said, you would have got a blank alert if this event fired properly...

Comment: I guess you are right. Working throgh a console is not much fun I can guarantee ;-) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is that you are binding to "onclick", instead of "click".

Answer (score 0):

You had it basically correct - don't forget to wrap your script in `$(document).ready(..)`, otherwise your script will try to bind it's event handlers before all of the elements have loaded. As noted above, you were also using onclick instead of `click`. You can also reference `this` directly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Dexter. I have used your short way of getting the id (this.id) instead of my long example

Answer (score 0):

From looking at what you are trying to do... you can't hide the `tbody` then unhide a portion of it. Try doing something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="#color2030" class="color">2030</a> 
<a href="#color2031" class="color">2031</a> 
<a href="#color2032" class="color">2032</a> 
<a href="#color2033" class="color">2033</a> 
<a href="#color2034" class="color">2034</a> 
<a href="#color2035" class="color">2035</a> 
<a href="#color2036" class="color">2036</a> 
<a href="#color2037" class="color">2037</a> 
<a href="#color2038" class="color">2038</a> 

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td id="color2030">2030</td>
   <td id="color2031">2031</td>
   <td id="color2032">2032</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="color2033">2033</td>
   <td id="color2034">2034</td>
   <td id="color2035">2035</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="color2036">2036</td>
   <td id="color2037">2037</td>
   <td id="color2038">2038</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('table tbody td').hide();
 $('a.color').click(function(){
  var selColor = $(this).attr('href');
  $('table tbody td').hide();
  $('td'+selColor).show();
 })
})
```

Comment: Sure I can :-) Well, it works. But you may be right that it is not the best code. Hiding all, then showing some works just fine. But thanks for your feedback, stackoverflow is great